# VBA Copy paste columns in different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets – Latency, TP. I need to copy col M from "Latency" and paste it into col D of "TP" only if "Latency" col E has the string “COMPATIBLE” and col O has the string “Pass”.

I have the below code, but it doesn't give any result.

I'm not sure whats wrong with it:

```
Sub sbMoveData()
Dim lRow As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
'Find last roe in Sheet1
 With Worksheets("Latency")
    lRow = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To lRow
        If UCase(.Range("E" & i)) = "COMPATIBLE" And UCase(.Range("O" & i)) = "Pass" Then
            .Range("M" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("TP").Range("D" & j)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Your code is testing cols E and O, but you say you want to test A and B. Is that a typo or are you actually testing the wrong cols?

Comment: Sorry its a Typo...Its COl E and Col O from Latency sheet. Will edit OP

Comment: In Clumn E" when you sat has the string "COMPATIBLE" do you mean exact match? or also might be "COMPATIBLE and other stuff" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub sbMoveData()
Dim lRow As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Latency")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TP")
'Find last roe in Sheet1

lRow = ws1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
j = 1
For i = 1 To lRow
    If ws1.Range("A" & i) = "COMPATIBLE" And ws1.Range("B" & i) = "Pass" Then
        ws1.Range("M" & i).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("D" & j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome. This works. How do i paste it into D2 instead of D1?

Comment: Just change j=1 to j=2.

Comment: Hello, i try this method in my case i have almost 20 columns to matched, and about 400 rows. It takes me 15 minutes. Is too long. Is this suppose to take that long?

Answer (score 2):

UCase(.Range("O" & i)) = "Pass"
Will always be false :-)

Comment: how do i fix this?

Comment: UCase(.Range("O" & i)) = "PASS"

Comment: @dgorti edit you answer and put your correction inside it

Answer (score 1):

You are never going to match UCase(Cell) = "Pass", right?  You either need to have:

```
UCase(.Range("O" & i)) = "PASS"
```

or

```
.Range("O" & i) = "Pass"
```