# Loop copy paste and paste special in different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to vba, and I'm trying not to use 'Select', but I can't figure out, how to do the code without it. I have three sheets (data sheet, generator sheet and picture sheet). I need to loop through the data sheet and copy a cell/value to a cell in the generator sheet. From here, copy a range and paste special as picture into the picture sheet (with Name, Width and OnAction) - then the next loop.
I've tried to do as in this link ([VBA Copy paste columns in different sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605835/vba-copy-paste-columns-in-different-sheet)) with the named worksheets. The problem is the paste special - here I can't make it work without selecting the picture sheet and the cell :-(

> ```
> For y = 1 To 1
> For x = 1 To lastrow
>     If Cells(x, y).Value >= 0 Then
>
>         IDnr = wsDAT.Cells(x, y).Value
>         wsDAT.Cells(x, y).Copy
>             række = wsDAT.Cells(x, y).Row + 3
>             'Sheets("Listegenerator").Select
>             ' Sætter IDnr
>             'Range("A1").Value = IDnr
>             wsGEN.Range("A1").Value = IDnr
>
>             ' Justerer højden for problemtype
>             wsGEN.Range("H10").Rows.AutoFit
>             rowH = wsGEN.Range("H10").RowHeight
>
>             If rowH > 30 Then
>                 wsGEN.Range("A1:A2").RowHeight = rowH / 2
>                 Else: wsGEN.Range("A1:A2").RowHeight = 15
>             End If
>
>             ' Kopierer område
>             wsGEN.Range("A1:E2").Copy
>             ' Indsætter som billede
>             Sheets("Indholdsfortegnelse").Select
>             Cells(række, y).Select
>             ' Billedenavn = IDnr
>             With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste
>                 .Name = IDnr
>                 .ShapeRange.Width = 425
>                 .Application.CutCopyMode = False
>                 ' Tildeler makro
>                 .OnAction = "Rediger_side"
>             End With
>
>             ' Indsætter link
>             wsPIC.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
>                 "X:\Globale Dokumenter\Arbejdsmiljø\APV'er\" & IDnr & _
>                 ".pdf", TextToDisplay:="Vis APV nr. " & IDnr
>
>
>         'Sheets("Filtreret_data").Select
>         'Cells(x + 1, y).Select
>
>     End If
> Next x
> Next y
> ```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Can you please provide the code you have so far, so we can see where you went wrong? We can't really see what your issue is without it.

Answer (score 0):

You do *Worksheets.Select* and *Range.Select*, then you refer to the selection as *ActiveSheet* and *ActiveCell*.

You can refer to these same objects directly **without selection** using *worksheets(1)* or *worksheets("sheet name")* and *range("A5")* or *cells(1,5)*.

When working with a range object (cells), it's vital to state in which worksheet the cell is located like this: *ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A5")*.

Where exactly isn't the code working?

---

EDIT after your comment:

```
 wsGEN.Range("A1:E2").CopyPicture
 With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste
            .Name = IDnr
            .ShapeRange.Width = 425
            .Application.CutCopyMode = False
            ' Tildeler makro
            .OnAction = "Rediger_side"
 End With
```

I hope it works. I didn't notice you were pasting a picture, sorry.

Comment: It has to be inserted as picture as the code above, but I tried the simple paste like `wsPIC.Range("A" & række).Paste` or `wsPIC.cells(række, y).Paste` or `wsPIC.Range("A4").Paste` instead of selecting worksheet and range. With this I get a Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. With 'select' as shown in the code above it works.  
I was just hoping to be free of 'selection'. How do I do it? The loop only needs to run about 350 times, so I'm not sure if 'select' has a big impact on the code.

Comment: Updated the answer. :)

Comment: `CopyPicture` Gives Run-time error '1004':. And when not selecting sheet and range the active sheet is not the correct sheet for the paste command.

Comment: I need someting to replace `Sheets("Indholdsfortegnelse").Select`
`Cells(række, y).Select`
` ' Billedenavn = IDnr`
`With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste`